# Binding lineargradientbrush color with property

Tags: c#, xaml, binding, properties, lineargradientbrush

I have a problem with color in gradientstop. I want binding offset color with my property that return color (System.Windows.Media), but not working and return defalt color Transparent. If binding same property with Foreground Label is working. This style is in ResourceDictionary.

```
<Style TargetType="{x:Type TabControl}">
    <Setter Property="Background">
        <Setter.Value>
            <LinearGradientBrush StartPoint="0 0" EndPoint="0 1">
                <LinearGradientBrush.GradientStops>
                    <GradientStop Offset="0.1" Color="Black" />
                    <GradientStop Offset="1" Color="{Binding Path=MyColor}" />
                </LinearGradientBrush.GradientStops>
            </LinearGradientBrush>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

and it's working:

```
<Style TargetType="{x:Type Label}">
    <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{Binding Path=MyColor, 
            Converter={StaticResource ColorToBrush}}" />
</Style>
```

my property is:

```
public Color MyColor
{
    set
    {
       myColor = value;
       NotifyPropertyChanged("MyColor");
    }
    get { return myColor; }
}
```

Thank you everybody for answers

Comment: I don't think you can bind elements within a style like that - because the datacontext is set on the control not the style. Perhaps you could try setting the background on the control instead of in the style and then bind it there?

Comment: I'm try setting the background on the control and working fine.
Thank's for the help.